# J2ME Telephone Query

Tags: java-me, mobile

1. I am retrieving telephone number from DB as string in J2ME
2. I want to make this telephone number appear as a link such that upon clicking it asks to make a call or send a message

In Gmail J2ME app telephone numbers & websites are automatically appearing as linkable text.....how is this possible???

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PIM API](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/pim/pim1/) for retrieve the telephone number from contacts.

Refer this [link](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/pim/index.html) for using PIM API.

Use [platformRequest](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_make_a_telephone_call_from_Java_ME) for make a call.

See this [link](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/sending-receiving-sms-on-j2me-device-4.html) for send SMS using WMA API.